# Trying to install Docker on RHEL - docker-ce conflicts with Podman-docker

Tags: linux, docker, rhel, podman

Getting this error:

Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                                      22 MB/s |  45 MB     00:02
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Mon 01 Aug 2022 17:36:44 BST.
Error:
Problem: problem with installed package podman-docker-2:4.0.2-6.module+el8.6.0+14877+f643d2d6.noarch

- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-2:4.0.2-6.module+el8.6.0+14877+f643d2d6.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1.0.0-2.git921f98f.module+el8+2785+ff8a053f.noarch
- package podman-docker-1.0.0-2.git921f98f.module+el8+2785+ff8a053f.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1.0.0-2.git921f98f.module+el8.0.0+2958+4e823551.noarch
- package podman-docker-1.0.0-2.git921f98f.module+el8.0.0+2958+4e823551.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1.0.5-1.gitf604175.module+el8.0.0+4017+bbba319f.noarch
- package podman-docker-1.0.5-1.gitf604175.module+el8.0.0+4017+bbba319f.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1.0.3-1.git9d78c0c.module+el8.0.0.z+3717+fdd07b7c.noarch
- package podman-docker-1.0.3-1.git9d78c0c.module+el8.0.0.z+3717+fdd07b7c.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch
- package podman-docker-1.4.2-5.module+el8.1.0+4240+893c1ab8.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package podman-docker-1.6.4-2.module+el8.1.1+5363+bf8ff1af.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package podman-docker-1.6.4-4.module+el8.1.1+5885+44006e55.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package podman-docker-1.6.4-10.module+el8.2.0+6063+e761893a.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1.4.2-6.module+el8.1.0+4830+f49150d7.noarch
- package podman-docker-1.4.2-6.module+el8.1.0+4830+f49150d7.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package podman-docker-1.9.3-2.module+el8.2.1+6867+366c07d6.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package podman-docker-1.6.4-11.module+el8.2.0+6368+cf16aa14.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package podman-docker-1.6.4-12.module+el8.2.0+6669+dde598ec.noarch conflicts with docker-ce provided by docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-2.0.5-5.module+el8.3.0+8221+97165c3f.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-2.2.1-7.module+el8.3.1+9857+68fb1526.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-3.0.1-6.module+el8.4.0+10607+f4da7515.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-3.0.1-7.module+el8.4.0+11311+9da8acfb.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-3.2.3-0.10.module+el8.4.0+11989+6676f7ad.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-3.2.3-0.11.module+el8.4.0+12050+ef972f71.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-3.3.1-9.module+el8.5.0+12697+018f24d7.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-2:4.0.2-6.module+el8.6.0+14673+621cb8be.noarch
- package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by podman-docker-1:3.4.2-9.module+el8.5.0+13852+150547f7.noarch
- cannot install the best candidate for the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before starting the Docker installation, you need to remove the conflicting packages, such as the `podman` and `buildah` packages, from your system.

Comment: Thx.  Containerd.io was conflicting with runc.  Removing docker-ce left Containerd.io, but after removing that the system could update again, and podman / podman-docker were working fine.  I was hoping to have Docker & Podman - but have given up on that and am running with Podman for now.